# Error while extracting response for type [class java.lang.Object] and content type [text/html;charset=UTF-8] -Html Response extracting

Tags: spring-boot, resttemplate, data-extraction

I am getting error in parsing a response from a rest template.
Below is the attach code snippet:

```
 UriComponents uriComponents =
                UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(someUrl).build();
        List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<>();
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        List<MediaType> mediaTypes = new ArrayList<>();
        mediaTypes.add(MediaType.TEXT_HTML);
        converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(mediaTypes);
        messageConverters.add(converter);
        restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);
  ResponseEntity<Object> response = restTemplate.exchange(uriComponents.toUri(), HttpMethod.POST, payload, Object.class);
```

The exception I am receiving is:

```
Error while extracting response for type [class java.lang.Object] and content type [text/html;charset=UTF-8]

org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null'); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: (sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream); line: 1, column: 2]
```

Expected API response from the Postman I am retrieving is :
[click to view response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJSxn.png)

Here in the response, the response is retrieving HTML content. How can I receive this response in the response of rest template I am triggering.

Comment: Are you hoping to retrieve JSON or HTML? For HTML, just try using `String` as response entity type, you can use the simpler [`postForObject`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#postForObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Class-java.util.Map-)

Comment: I am hoping to receive HTML. What should I pass in the last parameter, i.e. Map<String,?> uriVariables. I do not have any query param or something relevant for this api to be passed.

Comment: Could you check above response from the API via Postman I have attached. I need to get that response via rest template.

Comment: Not sure I follow, the image you posted shows a JSON response